# Coloring image in swift: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

Good day. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong in here, but I'm trying to color my image in viewWillAppear and then I when I click on a button it segue to the next controller. However when I colored, it's changing but when typing my button to segue it's breaking. Here's my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    let logo = UIImage(named: "UnifiedLogo.png")

    if let imageForLogo = logo{
        let templateImage = imageForLogo.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        print(templateImage)
        logoImageView.image = templateImage
        logoImageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

and the breaking line is shown in the bellow pic.

[breaking point with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgEoM.png)

[debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiBb2.png)

I have checked that outlets are linked and they are all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check outlet `logoImageView` is properly connected with ViewController?

Comment: @NiravD yes it is

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine one thing you will have to check is if the outlet of `imageview` is connected properly or not.

Comment: I did this even before I posted the question but nothing, I checked my outlets they're connected/

Comment: Have you tried your this code in viewDidLoad?Try it there.Should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear), the view isn't added yet in the view hierarchy when `viewWillAppear` is called :

> **view​Will​Appear(_:​)**
>
> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view

Thus, you can't refer to the view controller's oulets variables in it.

Instead, move your code in `viewDidLoad`, which is called once the view hierarchy is loaded  :

> **view​Did​Load()**
>
> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory.

Comment: I did this even before I posted the question but nothing, I checked my outlets they're connected/

Comment: @devSA `viewDidLoad` is the right place to put the code. If it's not working there, either the outlet is not connected, or it was connected but the view got deallocated. Put the code in `viewDidLoad` and remove the `weak` keyword from the `IBOutlet` declaration. If that doesn't make the problem go away, the connection is not there.